# Have multiple URIs with parameters in routes.js using MEAN

Tags: javascript, api, get, uri

I want to be able to use get methods in my MEAN API, i have the following code in my index.js:

```
router.route('/platillos/:id')
.get(PlatilloCtrl.getPlatillosById)
.post(upload.array(),PlatilloCtrl.addComentario)
.put(upload.array(),PlatilloCtrl.updatePlatillo)
.delete(PlatilloCtrl.deletePlatillo);
```

and I made this one too:

```
router.route('/platillosC/:categoria')
.get(PlatilloCtrl.getPlatillosByCategoria);
```

I would like to have the category and the id in the same URI withouth having an extra one.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly what you're using in terms of a routing solution, most libraries will accept and parse multiple parameters, ie:

```
router.route('/platillosC/:id/:categoria')
```

Comment: I'm so sorry, I'm kind of new at this, but i am working with MEAN stack, I was trying to understand a way to use multiples parameters, i read somthing like '/example/:param1?param2' but i don´t quite understand